# Thoughts on using emojis in logs

Tags: logging, emoji

I found it easier to follow through logs with Emojis. Symbols tend to explain themself a lot better than text.

Why could it be considered bad practice to do so ?

Thank your for your input.

Comment: I'd say it depends on who else may receive the log, if it's just you or a small team and you all feel it would help you in the way you interpret the logs, then definitely go for it. Icons can be ambiguous and being that logs are meant to detail exactly what's going in a program, I'm not sure where icons could realistically fit in better than some simple text when it comes to troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be "A picture is worth a thousand words." What may seem as a good emoji to you may seem bad to someone else may seem ambiguous to someone else. If you want to log emojis/pictures rather than text, a best-practice approach would be to have another referential file that describes each emoji with words. This way you can describe one emoji precisely with lines of text, but only log the simple emoji character. Now that character is universally understood.

Comment: I use it complementary to text so one can see more precisely if he wants to. 

I thinks it easier to spot certain logs when watching through all of them. A bit like if you would use red font color for dangerous and yellow for warnings.

Comment: With that then I see no issue with logging emojis, especially if your just trying to quickly identify problematic regions.